# How to use and package a JAR file with my Android app?

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, package, apk

I have an API in the form of a JAR that I would like to use in my Android app. Not sure if it should be part of the project in Eclipse or kept separate and added to the project properties. This JAR also needs to be packaged with the application, so how is that done for Android apps?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As explained by this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project):

- Your Project -> right click -> Import -> Archive File ->  `yourjar.jar`
- Your Project -> right click -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Jar -> `yourjar.jar`

You must add it as "external JAR" files, and set the "Order and Export" in your Eclipse project.

[image: eclipseexternallibrary2.png]

---

Update February 2012:

[Pacerier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/632951/pacerier) mentions in the comment having an issue (ClassNotFound) even though he did declare the library.
He had:

[image: class not found]

However, the solution was simple:

Over 1 hour wasted. Man was I pissed!
**Solution: make sure your JAR is compiled with 1.6 and not 1.7**.
Argh

Comment: Even after doing that, I'm getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: asd.asd.TESTActivity$1` what is missing?

Comment: @Pacerier not sure about the uses-library: you have other alternatives (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230268/android-how-to-use-uses-library)

Comment: I've tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/1337933/632951 as well, looks like its working for everyone except for me. This is how my screen looks like: http://screenshoot.me/LIDzgI do you know what *may* have been the problem?

Comment: Over 1 hour wasted. Man was i pissed! Solution: make sure your JAR is compiled with 1.6 and not 1.7. argh

Comment: @Pacerier good catch. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Would it fail if the jar classes had been compiled using Java 5?

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo it can be problematic if your Java JDK Compiler Compliance level isn't set to Java 5: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1431554/6309

Comment: @VonC +1 For your comment which could be an answer itself.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to **VonC** for pointing me in the right direction. I had the same symptoms but for a different library (I needed to add org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 for an Android project). The solution that worked for me was SLIGHTLY different. Herewith the steps that I followed:

1. Download library from http://commons.apache.org/codec/download_codec.cgi
2. Extract commons-codec-1.6.jar from the tarball and copy to a local
   folder
3. In eclipse:

   - right-click project name
   - choose "Properties" from context menu
   - on "Libraries" tab, select "Add External JARs..."
   - navigate to and select commons-codec-1.6.jar from the location you extracted it to your local drive
4. The jar file will now appear under "referenced Libraries" in your Package Explorer and you will be able to reference the library in your code.