# Android/Java referenced library issues - NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, android, decode

I have been getting a NoSuchMethodError from an external library that I am using in Eclipse. I'm trying to run a parser that gets VCard data and decodes it, using 
[this](https://code.google.com/p/ez-vcard/) library, which ships with all its dependencies (including the packages mentioned in the logcat below). I have added all of the dependencies to my References Libraries in Eclipse via Build Path -> Add External JARs. However whenever I run my code, I get:

```
06-02 11:08:53.126: I/dalvikvm(7576): Could not find method org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64, referenced from method ezvcard.types.BinaryType.parse
06-02 11:08:53.126: W/dalvikvm(7576): VFY: unable to resolve static method 12383: Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64;.decodeBase64 (Ljava/lang/String;)[B
06-02 11:08:53.126: D/dalvikvm(7576): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x003c
06-02 11:08:53.137: I/dalvikvm(7576): Could not find method org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64, referenced from method ezvcard.types.BinaryType.cannotUnmarshalValue
06-02 11:08:53.146: W/dalvikvm(7576): VFY: unable to resolve static method 12383: Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64;.decodeBase64 (Ljava/lang/String;)[B
06-02 11:08:53.146: D/dalvikvm(7576): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0018
06-02 11:08:53.426: D/dalvikvm(7576): GC_CONCURRENT freed 295K, 12% free 3846K/4328K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 64ms
06-02 11:08:53.426: D/dalvikvm(7576): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 30ms
06-02 11:08:53.486: D/AndroidRuntime(7576): Shutting down VM
06-02 11:08:53.496: W/dalvikvm(7576): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-02 11:08:53.546: E/AndroidRuntime(7576): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-02 11:08:53.546: E/AndroidRuntime(7576): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64
06-02 11:08:53.546: E/AndroidRuntime(7576):     at ezvcard.types.BinaryType.parse(BinaryType.java:467)
06-02 11:08:53.546: E/AndroidRuntime(7576):     at ezvcard.types.BinaryType.doUnmarshalText(BinaryType.java:331)
06-02 11:08:53.546: E/AndroidRuntime(7576):     at ezvcard.types.VCardType.unmarshalText(VCardType.java:279)
06-02 11:08:53.546: E/AndroidRuntime(7576):     at ezvcard.io.VCardReader.readNext(VCardReader.java:355)
06-02 11:08:53.546: E/AndroidRuntime(7576):     at com.lim.json.VCardActivity.getVCard(VCardActivity.java:76)
06-02 11:08:53.546: E/AndroidRuntime(7576):     at com.lim.json.VCardActivity.onCreate(VCardActivity.java:54)
06-02 11:08:53.546: E/AndroidRuntime(7576):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-02 11:08:53.546: E/AndroidRuntime(7576):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-02 11:08:53.546: E/AndroidRuntime(7576):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-02 11:08:53.546: E/AndroidRuntime(7576):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-02 11:08:53.546: E/AndroidRuntime(7576):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-02 11:08:53.546: E/AndroidRuntime(7576):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-02 11:08:53.546: E/AndroidRuntime(7576):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-02 11:08:53.546: E/AndroidRuntime(7576):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-02 11:08:53.546: E/AndroidRuntime(7576):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-02 11:08:53.546: E/AndroidRuntime(7576):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-02 11:08:53.546: E/AndroidRuntime(7576):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-02 11:08:53.546: E/AndroidRuntime(7576):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-02 11:08:53.546: E/AndroidRuntime(7576):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-02 11:08:53.546: E/AndroidRuntime(7576):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-02 11:12:04.456: I/Process(7576): Sending signal. PID: 7576 SIG: 9
06-02 11:12:05.136: E/Trace(7639): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-02 11:12:05.666: D/gralloc_goldfish(7639): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-02 11:12:06.276: D/dalvikvm(7639): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 92K, 8% free 2675K/2888K, paused 56ms, total 66ms
06-02 11:12:06.286: I/dalvikvm-heap(7639): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.333MB for 635812-byte allocation
06-02 11:12:06.346: D/dalvikvm(7639): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 7% free 3290K/3512K, paused 50ms, total 50ms
06-02 11:12:06.427: D/dalvikvm(7639): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 6% free 3308K/3512K, paused 19ms+13ms, total 87ms
06-02 11:12:06.676: I/Choreographer(7639): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Thing is, I have checked the  org.apache.commons.codec.binary package in my References Libraries and the Base64.decodeBase64 method certainly exists. What gives?

Answer (score 1):

From the answers to [other similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047706/apache-commons-codec-with-android-could-not-find-method) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147789/nosuchmethoderror-using-commonc-codec-in-android-application), it would appear that Android includes the 1.2 commons codec library which must appear first on the classpath.  That version does not include the `byte[]` version of the `decodeBase64` method.

One possible solution would be to change the EZVCard source (since it is open source) to call the `String` based method instead.

Comment: Hm, it doesn't seem like I can edit the source inside Eclipse - clicking on the class files brings up documentation only. Would it be possible for me to remove/replace the 1.2 commons library with the 1.6 one? Since I doubt this will be the only problem - might be easier to replace rather than continually edit the EZVCard source code.

Comment: It would appear it's not possible to change the libraries that Google include with Android (there's a request open to change the dependency though: https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/issues/detail?id=75).  Have you downloaded a copy of EZVCard with source code included?  Also, you'll need to extract the files from the jar before you can edit them.

Comment: Oh, okay, I have the source already and have attached it to the jar, thanks. :) But I can't seem to edit it at all? Is there something else I have to do before the source is modifiable?

Comment: Have you extracted the files from the jar?  You can do it from the command line using `jar -xf /path/to/archive.jar`, or using any zip utility (as it's the same format).

Comment: But I can only import a .jar as a source for the referenced library, it seems? How will I import the extracted files after I have extracted them?

Comment: In exactly the same way that you 'import' your own `.java` source files.