# NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/cdt/core/CCorePlugin

Tags: eclipse, noclassdeffounderror, eclipse-cdt

I am developing a plugin to create/compile/run CDT Project through a java code using eclipse Indigo.
I can run my plugin in Eclipse PDE successfully.
But when I deploy it to a jar file, and install it in a new eclipse-java-indigo-win32,
I could not run my plugin.
it gives the below error.

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/cdt/core/CCorePlugin
    at    sourceanalysistoolplugin.wizards.CDTProjectManager.createCDTProj(CDTProjectManager.java:43)
at sourceanalysistoolplugin.intermediate.SourceCompileManager.createProject(SourceCompileManager.java:38)
at sourceanalysistoolplugin.actions.SATMenuCompileActionDelegate.run(SATMenuCompileActionDelegate.java:63)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.runWithEvent(WWinPluginAction.java:229)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$6.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:452)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.cdt.core.CCorePlugin
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 32 more
```

I have added org.eclipse.cdt.core jar file in plugin dependencies tab.

Please guide me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem and tried a number of different "solutions" (some of which worked for others, but none of which worked for me). I finally discovered that [How to use and package a JAR file with my Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316445/how-to-use-and-package-a-jar-file-with-my-android-app) has the answer (at least for me) -- I had to recompile the jar using JDK 1.6. Compiling with 1.7 never worked. As soon as I recompiled and reloaded the new jar, it worked great. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment balinjdl...Unfortunately I am using JDK 1.6..Seems like this is different..

Comment: JDK 1.6 updates have screwed things up a bit. So moving to 1.7 may not be such a bad idea.